# Centrar verticalmente imagen en contenedor

Tags: html, css, contenedor

Tengo un contenedor div (id="columna3") y una imagen (id="user"). La misma quiero posicionarla a la derecha, eso está bien, lo hago con position:absolute y right: 0px. Pero la misma no está centrada verticalmente. He intentado ya que la imagen tiene position absolute     height: 50%; bottom: 50%; pero la imagen sube a la parte superior del div.

Cualquier ayuda se lo agradecería. Saludos.

```
 #columna3{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    text-align: left;
    border: solid;
    border-color: red;
  }

  #user{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
 
  }
```

He intentado:

```
  #user{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
  }
```

Pero la imagen sube a la parte superior del contenedor.

Comment: Ayudaría mucho agregues tu HTML

Comment: Es solo un div con una imagen adentro.. No agregué el código porque es en React JS con el framework Ionic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comentarios:

- No ocupamos posicionamiento, en su lugar sácale mas provecho a flexbox
- Usa como ya te dicen `align-items` para mover al centro de forma vertical tu imagen
- Usa justify-content con valor de `flex-end` para que horizontalmente la imagen se desplaze a la derecha de su etiqueta contenedora
- Elimina las siguientes reglas, ya no serán necesarias:

  - **`right: 0px;`**
  - **`height: 50%;`**
  - **`bottom: 50%;`**
- Si por ejemplo deseas que la imagen no quede totalmente pegada al margen derecho de su contenedor, entonces le puedes aplicar un `margin-right` con un valor específico que ayude a moverla

**Ejemplo 1:**

```html
    <style>
      .contenedor {
        background-color: teal;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
      }
      
      .contenedor-img {
        background-color: crimson;
        height: 120px;
        width: 120px;
      }
    </style>
    
    <div class="contenedor">
      <img src="" alt="" class="contenedor-img">
    </div>
```

**Ejemplo 2:**

```html
    <style>
      .contenedor {
        background-color: teal;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
      }
      
      .contenedor-img {
        background-color: crimson;
        height: 120px;
        width: 120px;
        margin-right: 15px;
      }
    </style>
    
    <div class="contenedor">
      <img src="" alt="" class="contenedor-img">
    </div>
```

Salvo que un requerimiento de tu maquetación dicte un posicionamiento determinado, yo quitaría esa instrucción, cuando haces uso de flexbox tienes la posibilidad de indicar como de *distribuirán* las cajas internas del contenedor.

**Lecturas de interés**

- [Módulo Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)
- [CSS Flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/)

Comment: gracias. Que el contenedor de la imagen tenga una altura de 120px es por algo?

Comment: @Julian solo fue para construir el ejemplo, pero tú dale las medidas que requieres

Answer (score 1):

Para centrar la imagen podrías ponerle a columna3 el siguiente código

```css
 #columna3{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; //esto lo que hace es centrar todos lo elementos hijos verticalmente
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    border: solid;
    border-color: red;
  }

  #user{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
 
  }
```

te puedes guiar con esta imagen y revisar documentación acerca de Flexbox.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aquí `right: 0px;` no hace falta el `px`

Comment: Gracias. He implementado el código pero la imagen queda en la parte inferior del container div.